# Tesseract projection into $3D$

Tags: geometry, rotations, projective-geometry

[image]

I found [this](http://www.math.harvard.edu/archive/21b_fall_03/4dcube/index.html):

> The tesseract is a four dimensional cube. It has 16 edge points $v=(a,b,c,d)$, with $a,b,c,d$ either equal to $+1$ or $-1$. Two points are connected, if their distance is $2$. Given a projection $P(x,y,z,w)=(x,y,z)$ from four dimensional space to three dimensional space, we can visualize the cube as an object in familiar space. The effect of a linear transformation like a rotation
>   $$
> R(t)=\pmatrix{1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0&\\0&0&\cos(t)&\sin(t)\\0&0&-\sin(t)&\cos(t)}
> $$
>   in $4D$ space can be visualized in $3D$ by viewing the points $v(t) = P R(t) v$ in $\mathbb R^3$.

So how does $P$ actually look?

Comment: Have you noticed that your link is dead. Could you replace it by a "living" one ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The particular $P$ used to make your animation loop looks like projection away from a point directly above the the $4$-cube. Intuitively, put a light source at $\mathbf{c} = (0, 0, 0, h)$ and map each point $\mathbf{x} = (x, y, z, w)$  with $w \neq h$ to its "shadow", the intersection of $\mathbf{R}^3 \times \{0\}$ with the ray from $\mathbf{c}$ through $\mathbf{x}$:
$$
P(x, y, z, w) = \frac{h}{h - w}(x, y, z).
$$

If we assume the $4$-cube has edges of length $2$ and is centered at the origin (i.e., it's the $1$-skeleton of the $4$-fold Cartesian product $[-1, 1]^{4}$), then $h \approx 3$: When the $4$-cube is aligned with the coordinate axes (so the projection looks like a small cube nested in a large cube, with corresponding vertices joined), the "top face" looks about twice as large as the "bottom face".

Comment: I think I begin to see: We have a scaling factor $\frac h{h-w}$ and a $z$ component that changes with $t$ accoriding to $R(t)$. But then I would expect two coordinates of each vertex to just move in and out by the scaling. In the gif it looks like they move on orbits...

Comment: If you look down the axis of the cube along which the orbiting motion occurs (i.e., along the axis most nearly pointing toward the viewer), those two coordinates _do_ just move in and out radially. :)